# Prove that the set $X := \{(x_1, ... , x_n) : \forall_{1 \leq i \leq n} -M \leq x_i \leq M \}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Prove that the set $X := \{(x_1, ... , x_n) : \forall_{1 \leq i \leq n} -M \leq x_i \leq M \}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$

Here is my solution:

First prove that if a sequence of Real numbers $\{a_n \}$ converging to $a$ satisfies $|a_n| < M$, then $|a| < M$.

assume that $\{a_n\}$ is sequence converging to $a$ that satisfies $|a_n| < M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose $|a| > M$.

We have:

$\forall_{\epsilon >0} \exists_{N \geq1} \forall_{n \geq N} |a_n - a| < \epsilon$

Then pick $\epsilon = a - M$

$|a - a_n| < a - M$

$a - a_n < a - M$

$M < a_n$ which is a contradiction as $|a_n| < M$

Using this fact:

If we pick a sequence of points $x_n$ in $X$ converging to a, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = a \implies \forall_{1 \leq i \leq n}\lim_{n \to \infty} x_i = a_i$ where $x_i$ and $a_i$ are the ith components of $x_n$ and a, respectively.

From the definition of $X$, we have that $|x_i| \leq M$, and from the fact that we proved previously it follows that $|a_i| < M$. This means that $a \in X$, so this set is closed.

is this proof ok?

Comment: Looks good! The only (perhaps non-trivial) fact you may want to prove if you havent already, is that if a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ converges, then each component converges in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Your first assumption is wrong… but it holds $$|a_n| < M \Rightarrow |a| \le M$$

Comment: Your lemma isn't true.  The sequence $a_n = 1-\frac{1}{n}$ is bounded by $1$, but converges to $1$.  But if you change $|a|< M$ to $|a|\leq M$, it's true.

Comment: Much too complicated as a products of two closed sets is closed  extends by induction to any finite product.

Answer (score 1):

$$X= \bigcap_{i=1}^n \pi_i^{-1}[[-M,M]]$$ where $\pi_i$ is the projection onto the $i$-th coordinate (which is continuous), and $[-M,M]$ is closed in $\Bbb R$. Intersections of closed sets are closed. Hence $X$ is.